# How to fix Microsoft Store package validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, xaml-islands

I'm developing a `WPF` application, I added a custom WinRT component (implemented in `UWP`) and I'm hosting this win10 component in the `WPF` app, via XamlHost. I followed every step of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands), my custom controls are implemented in a `UWP app project` instead of a `UWP class library`. The app runs well and the `UWP` components are displayed properly in the `WPF` application. I could create the app package, but when I uploaded to the Microsoft Store (the `.msixupload` file), the following error was thrown:

```
Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages. Please upload the Microsoft Store appxupload file and try again.
```

What they mean pre-compiled .NET Native packages?

I also checked the [sample application](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples), which contains a [winrthost.dll](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Managed/UWPApplication/WinRTHost) for different architectures. However the documentation doesn't mention this, I also added to my UWP project and configured as it is in the sample app's `.csproj` file. I tried to remove this dll file, but the store still doesn't accept the build.

As I removed the reference to the `UWP App` project, the Store accepted my build. As I re-added the reference (without using any component from it), the Store rejected. So I think the problem is in the custom UWP app, but what could be a pre-compiled .NET Native package here?

**Update:**

I added a new empty UWP app project to the solution, just set up the XamlApplication and referenced it from the `WPF` application. The UWP component shows in the WPF (I added just a green rectangle), but when I tried to upload to the store, it displayed the same error message.

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands) says, also tried to create a UWP class library instead of the UWP app. Created the build and the store accepted... What is the difference?

The documentation says:

> You can alternatively define the custom control in the UWP app project
> you created in the previous section. However, these steps do this in a
> separate class library project for illustrative purposes because this
> is typically how custom controls are implemented for portability.

So, theoretically it would be possible to publish a WPF app with a custom WinRT component hosted in a UWP app, right? Then why the store doesn't accepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day of investigation, I found that the solution is just to **add the `UWP app` as a reference to the Packaging project** (not just to the `WPF app`).

As I added to the references, the Store accepted the build. More details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3488).